Field Maps Designer - duplicate form failed
I want to duplicate the Field Maps Designer form and use it in another layer. I read about it here:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-maps/field-mobility/duplicate-maps-and-forms-for-use-in-field-maps/?srsltid=AfmBOopXq2HhkaSybJsJ1s-dC0dV8JHy-H2WmwiAyKmBlalBo9dA2yfe
and tried to reproduce the form by uploading the JSON code.
What I have done is:

copy the FormInfo section to my new map (which refers to the analog layer)
copy the field content in fieldInfos within the popupInfo section to my new map (which refers to the analog layer)
copy the fieldInfos section from "old" layer to the "new" analog layer exactly in the same section

Unfortunately it's still something missing, as I keep seeing the box informing me, that all these fields have been removed from the layer.

As a result, I can't do anything with them - neither create the list nor set the layer type.
Moreover, the popups also don't work properly. I see the fields loaded, but they don't appear.

I think, that the ESRI doesn't explain this process well enough.
How can I replicate/duplicate the Field Maps Designer form successfully?
I want to have:

the same form with fields in analog layer
the same popups in analog new layer


You mention uploading JSON in attempt to duplicate the form, have you tried any of the other options that page mentions that you point to? e.g. The duplicate button or AGOL assistant?

The Field Maps Designer doesn't have the duplicate button. I can only save the form to the layer, but it doesn't help me at all.
